# Finding 3 consecutive duplicate char characters in an array?

Tags: java, arrays

I am having some problems trying to replace 3 consecutive duplicate char characters in an array. I want to find those 3 values and replaces them with x's. So far this is what I have:

```
public static char[] replaceSets(char [] input) {
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        for(int j = i+1; j < input.length; j++)
            for(int k = j+1; k < input.length; k++) {
                if ((input[i] == input[j]) && (input[j] == input[k])) {
                    input[i] = 'x';
                    input[j] = 'x';
                    input[k] = 'x';
                }
            }
    }
    return input;
}
```

However, if I have:

```
char[] input = {'r','y','y','r','r','g','b','y','y','y','r','g'};
```

It prints out:

```
xxxxxgbxyyrg
```

But, it should be:

```
ryyrrgbxxxrg
```

Comment: You don't need 3 separate loops for this, and 3 loops won't do what you want. Use a single for loop and add to `i` inside the loop (i.e. second character from the current index would be `input[i+1]`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need 3 loops to do this. You can take the following approach:

```
public static char[] replaceSets(char[] input) {
    if (input.length < 3) {
        return input;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < input.length - 3; ++i) {
        if (input[i] == input[i + 1] && input[i + 1] == input[i + 2]) {
            input[i] = 'x';
            input[i + 1] = 'x';
            input[i + 2] = 'x';
            i += 2;
        }
    }

    return input;
}
```

The function loops over the character array and tries to compare if characters at `i`, `i + 1`, `i + 2` positions are same. If so simply replace them with `'x'`.